# Inconsistent number of columns

Tags: python, csv, encoding, emeditor

- I have Parcels_All.csv which I compiled by merging many smaller
  parcel files, using the command line copy *.csv
- I have WKT_Revisions_Combined.csv that needs to go into
  Parcels_All.csv to update certain sections of data.
- I have vlookup.py script that can print the data from
  WKT_Revisions_Combined.csv into Parcels_All.csv by referencing row
  ID's and column headers.

Vlookup.py has not been able to successfully run because it seems there is an error within Parcels_All.csv. When I open the file in EmEditor (a big data text editor) it gives the error message "Inconsistent number of columns detected" for a few rows

The interesting thing is when I open Parcels_All.csv in Excel the data is organized and in place; no inconsistent columns.

Any thoughts? Could it be an encoding issue?

Answer (score 0):

When a CSV file with different number of columns are imported to Excel, the differences in row lengths are not evident. Excel has an infinitely wide table by default, so the real size of the CSV file is not shown. I suspect there are empty fields in the last column somewhere, because these would not be evident in Excel.